# Error on runner when testing with Robolectric

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, gradle, robolectric

I am currently trying to test my android application but I get an error on

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithPreJackPackagedLibrariesForDebug'.
> com.android.sched.scheduler.RunnerProcessException: Error during 'EmptyClinitRemover' runner on 'static void org.robolectric.annotation.Config.<clinit>() (Config.java:38-39)'
```

I am unsure why I am getting this error and have looked around for solutions but haven't found anything which could fix this issue.

My gradle file has this for Robolectric

```
dependencies {
compile('org.robolectric:robolectric:3.3') {
    exclude group: 'com.google.guava', module: 'guava'
}
}
```

Comment: change `compile` to `testCompile`

Comment: Up-voted. Facing the same problem.